# Replace while loop in series calculation

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I would like to understand how to replace this simple while loop with less characters.

```
a:
2017-12-31 10
2018-1-1 9
2018-1-2 15
2018-1-3 25
2018-1-4 30
```

I would like to replace this code with a shorter code:

```
b=pd.Series(index=a.index)
b[0]=0
i=1
while i< len(b):
    b[i]=a[i]*0.1+b[i-1]*0.9
    i+=1
```

Comment: "Efficient" as in, faster? Or fewer lines of code? I don't think you can go much faster than the O(N) algorithm you have now. But there are probably a couple of comparable approaches that take fewer than six lines.

Comment: yup fewer lines of code it's what i want!
I just would like to understand different way of coding to have more possibilities.

Comment: What is a's type? Is it a string? I'm guessing not, since that way I get a `TypeError` on b's creation. Can you provide a [mcve] that includes the creation of `a`?

Comment: fewer lines is not the same as more efficient.  please elaborate in the question, do you want better performance or literally just less characters?

Comment: a type is float

Comment: `a` is a single floating point number? Strange. I wouldn't expect printing a float to give you five lines of datetimes.

Comment: a has an index composed by date and corresponding float value

Comment: A `for` loop will make the code shorter by two lines. Using `;` you can reduce it to one line. Who cares about lines anyway? Vertical space is cheap :)

Comment: ok, i thought there where something more shorter! ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**
It's always best to provide a definitive way to reconstruct your data.  With this code, others can play with it to figure out stuff.

```
a = pd.Series(
    [10, 9, 15, 25, 30],
    pd.date_range('2017-12-31', periods=5)
)
```

---

**Solution**
Use Pandas' [**`pd.Series.ewm`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ewm.html) method with an `alpha` parameter set to `.9`

```
a.ewm(alpha=.9).mean()

2017-12-31    10.000000
2018-01-01     9.090909
2018-01-02    14.414414
2018-01-03    23.942394
2018-01-04    29.394294
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

---

To more closely match what your code does, use the `adjust=False` option with `alpha=.1`

```
a.ewm(alpha=.1, adjust=False).mean()

2017-12-31    10.0000
2018-01-01     9.9000
2018-01-02    10.4100
2018-01-03    11.8690
2018-01-04    13.6821
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too (-: